# Using dplyr to transform two columns to 625 columns

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a function `my_function` that takes two arbitrary-length numeric vectors and transforms those to a single numeric vector that has 625 dimensions.

I have a dataframe `data` that includes three columns: a factor Group, a numeric variable X, and a numeric variable Y.

I want to do an operation along these lines:

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
  group_by(Group) %>%
  summarize(my_625_new_columns=my_function(X, Y))
```

The result should be a 626 column dataframe: one column Group and then 625 columns corresponding to each element in the output of my_function. There should be one row per group.

Is this possible to do within dplyr's framework?

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ddply` from `plyr` for this.  `do` also works from `dplyr`.

```
## Some data
set.seed(0)
dat <- data.frame(Group=factor(rep(1:2, 100)), X=rnorm(100), Y=rnorm(100))

## A random function to apply to groups
## returns data.frame with same number of columns as length of x and y
func <- function(x, y) as.data.frame(t( (x+y)/2 ))

library(plyr)
res <- ddply(dat, .(Group), function(x) {
    func(x$X, x$Y)
})
res
#   Group        V1        V2         V3         V4         V5         V6
# 1     1  1.022407 0.3569047 -0.3578722 -1.1046582 -0.2532319  0.1755368
# 2     2 -0.551505 0.6595048 -0.4816156  0.6653634  2.0414753 -0.8856480
# ...

## With `do` from dplyr
library(dplyr)
dat %>% group_by(Group) %>% do(func(.$X, .$Y))
```